# How to change TextView text in intro slider?

Tags: android

I built intro slider with 4 layouts.I want to change `TextView` text in slide one but code doesn't work (activity doesn't know any view). How can I do that?

**IntroActivity.java:**

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppIntro {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

        addSlide(IntroSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_layout1));
        addSlide(IntroSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_layout2));
        addSlide(IntroSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_layout3));
        addSlide(IntroSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_layout4));

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout1,null);
        TextView tvSlide1 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSlide1Title);
        tvSlide1.setText("Text changed!");

    }
}
```

**IntroSlide.java:**

```
public class IntroSlide extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID = "layoutResId";
    private int layoutResId;

    public static IntroSlide newInstance(int layoutResId) {
        IntroSlide introSlide = new IntroSlide();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID, layoutResId);
        introSlide.setArguments(args);

        return introSlide;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID))
            layoutResId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
    @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inflated view isn't attached to any activity. you are just inflating it and setting text. which is not on the screen.

to change the text you need to keep reference of each view that you have added.

Comment: @Prashant Can you type code here?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiy your `onCreateView()' like below

```
TextView tvSlide1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
    tvSlide1 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSlide1Title);  
}

public void setSlideText(String text){
    tvSlide1.setText(text);
}
```

And in your **IntroActivity.java**

```
IntroSlide slide1 = IntroSlide.newInstance(R.layout.slide_layout1)
addSlide(slide1);
slide1.setSlideText("some text");
```